# Champions with physical changes from items?

Tags: league-of-legends

Is there any other champions that changes their appearance from items/etc? Considering that such don't have/wear skins.

E.g Cho'g and Zac's size depends on their HP, that they grow large enough if they reach like 3k+ HP or something.

Another is Rengar who changes his appereance from gaining stacks on his Necklace (I don't know if this is true but I'm around 80% sure that he gains something new on his apperance from stacks).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Currently there are no champions that change their physical appearance depending on the Item they buy.

However there are some cases in which special audio or visual effects are triggered:

**Primetime Draven**
If you buy Different Items on Draven he will often use a quote:

- Infinity Edge: "Look out, Draven's got his Infinity Edge!"
- Phantom Dancer: "That's a Phantom Dancer on Draven!"
- Bloodthirster: "Draven has finished his Bloodthirster!"
- Trinity Force:  "Wow, that's tons o' damage!"
- Nashors Tooth: "Why would Draven get a Nashor's Tooth? Because Draven."

**Shopkeepers on Howling Abyss**
Sometimes buying an Item triggers a special Quote

- Shard of True Ice: "Be careful with that. True Ice is powerful stuff."
- Frozen Mallet: "I crushed my share of skulls with that one!"
- Seekers Armguard:  "The seeker was a respected leader of the Tribe, but some say she betrayed us..."

**Items that have Visual effects**
Now this is the same for all champions. As far as I know there are no Individual exceptions.

- Runaan's Hurricane: A small Orb (hurricane) flies next to the champion
- Every Aura Item: Usually shows a small indicator under the champion.
- Banshees Veil: White-Blue Bubble around the champion.
- Spellblades/Muramana: Hands of the champions glow if the effect will be applied
- Face of the mountain + Sub-Items: Fireballs that fly around the champion.

**Champions that passively change their appearance**
These Champions change their appearance passively according to Situation.

- Kha'Zix: Body changes on Spending Evolution Points
- Cho Gath: Size changes according to ultimate stacks
- Zac: Size changes depending on how much health he has

Now these may not be all the Items/Champions/Actions that there are in the game but if you take a look at the wiki, you will usually find some additional information to it. Also I'm pretty sure that Rengar doesn't change his appearance based on how many stacks he has (Can't find a reference and also from Personal experience).

Comment: So it's just that Chog and Zac are really special, then.

Comment: @Randomizer pretty much yeah. Well I guess it's possible that they will release some champions/skins which interact with items/situations, but for now that would be all of it. I excluded legendary skins in the list because they are skins and not champions.

Comment: I believe twitch and braum (100% sure about braum) have special quotes when buying items. For example when Braum buys shoes he says: "These shoes, they are... too tight"

Comment: Don't forget sunfire also changes visual effect,and pulsefire Ezreal changes animations as he level up.

Comment: @SSilicon well sunfire counts as an aura item

Comment: might also also add that Syndra also changes "appearance" when her spells are being mastered

Comment: As always, you provide a perfect answer on the LoL topics :).